# Как передать данные с сервера клиенту и обратно, не через URL?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

Как передать данные с сервера клиенту и обратно, не через URL? я искал в интернете способ как передать данные не через URL, там были разные варианты, к примеру через тело пакетов, но конкретных примеров реализации, как на c#, так и на react.js не было, можете сбросить ссылку или привести пример того как это можно сделать?
Единственное что смог написать сам это то, как вернуть данные с БД в JSON формате

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AboutController : Controller {
        IRepository<Mans> db;

        public AboutController() {
            db = new MansRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        //[Authorize(Roles ="Administrator")]
        public IEnumerable<Mans> Index() {
            return db.GetList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: через URL это GET, а вам скорее всего нужен POST, добро пожаловать на первую страницу учебника по HTTP

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть в сторону сокетов